# Which is the best layout in android we can use to design the UI?

Tags: android, layout

I am using Absolute layout for my UI design in android.

My doubt is which layout is best for UI design in android and Is it the design is change in any other device. That means i am using HTC Desire to test my application if i installed my app in any other app means the design is change or look like same

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout` is definitely worst-practice for android.

Get to love the `RelativeLayout`.  It will make your life much easier, when designing for multiple resolutions/densities.  If you have an old SDK, update your eclipse plugin.  It has graphical snap-lines for RelativeLayouts similar to designing a form in Visual Studio, so you can see what is anchored where.  It's really quite good.

Answer (score 9):

Do **not** use AbsoluteLayout!  The Android Doc says:

> This class is deprecated. **Use
>   FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or a
>   custom layout instead**.

Those layouts will adapt to different screen sizes, whereas AbsoluteLayout will not.

Comment: Definitely right. I recommend RelativeLayout since it keeps the view hierachy flat. It takes some time to get used to it, but its well worth it imho.

Comment: @alextsc Agreed!  The latest updates to the Eclipse plugin make it even easier to use RelativeLayout as well.

Comment: Can we use Absolute layout inside the Relative layout.Is that make any problem

Answer (score 5):

I always go for LinearLayout over all other layout.Working with RelativeLayout is very hard as all the components are placed relatively to each other so if you want to move a component slightly you will have to sweat it out!!

Comment: But LinearLayout takes more time to load the view rather then RelativeLayout

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your design. It's a nice question. Layouts are a very important concept of desiging. I usually prefer linearLayout and relative layout.

Use frameLayout if you want to display a textView on an ImageView and don't worry about different handsets. It will adapt accordingly. Study Nine-patch image.